# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{xy(x^2 \sin y^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of following differential equation:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{xy(x^2 \sin (y^2)+1)}$$

Could someone hint me something to get through this problem?

Comment: One thing to try: Multiplying both sides by $2y$ yields
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{x(x^2\sin(y^2)+1)}$$
Now try the substitution $u = y^2$. The equation becomes
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2}{x(x^2\sin(u)+1)}$$
Still quite ugly, though.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)+%3D+1%2F(xy(x%5E2sin(y%5E2)+%2B+1))) says that 
$$
\frac{e^{y^2}}{8x^2}+\frac{e^{y^2}}{16}  (\sin(y^2)-\cos(y^2)) = C
$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration. It's not a solution, but at least the derivative is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

As @Nicholas Stull suggested, let $u=y^2$ so that
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac2{x\left(x^2\sin(y^2)+1\right)}$$
Then rearrange to Bernoulli's differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{du}-\frac12x=\frac12x^3\sin u$$
We may substitute $x=v^n$, and if $n-1=3n$, the dependence on the dependent variable on the right hand side will vanish. So $n=-\frac12$, $x=v^{-\frac12}$, and
$$\frac{dv}{du}+v=-\sin u$$
This is a first order linear differential equation with integrating factor
$$\mu=e^{\int1du}=e^u$$
So
$$\frac d{du}\left(e^uv\right)=e^u\frac{dv}{du}+e^uv=-e^u\sin u$$
Then
$$e^uv=-\frac{(e^u\sin u-e^u\cos u)}2+C$$
$$v=-\frac12\sin u+\frac12\cos u+Ce^{-u}$$
In terms of $x$ and $y$,
$$\frac1{x^2}=-\frac12\sin(y^2)+\frac12\cos(y^2)+Ce^{-y^2}$$
Which agrees nicely with the Wolfram|Alpha solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [exact differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation). You can solve it using the method described at the Wiki page. Note that the obtain solution will be implicit, i.e. of the form $F(x,y) = c$. In this particular case, it is not possible to write this in the form $y = f(x)$. However, you can write $x$ in terms of $y$.